# How to get authorization code on the server side without client having

Tags: javascript, authorization, spotify

I am making personal website that has a section that shows my most listened music from Spotify. To do this I need an authorization code to exchange for the access token. But for me to get that authorization code its requiring me to login. Is there a  way of login in on the server side without showing that login dialog?

```
const clientId = "bb***************************";
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const code = params.get("code");

if (!code) {
    redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId);
    
} else {
    console.log(code);
   // const accessToken = await getAccessToken(clientId, code);
   
}


async function redirectToAuthCodeFlow(clientId) {
    // TODO: Redirect to Spotify authorization page
    const verifier = generateCodeVerifier(128);
    const challenge = await generateCodeChallenge(verifier);

    localStorage.setItem("verifier", verifier);

    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("client_id", clientId);
    params.append("response_type", "code");
    params.append("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:5173/");
    params.append("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
    params.append("code_challenge_method", "S256");
    params.append("code_challenge", challenge);
    
    var url = `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?${params.toString()}`;    
    document.location = url;
    
     
}
```